# Kivy, functions, clases and methods

Tags: android, python, kivy

Im new in kivy, I have some questions, hope you can help me.

**First**
I would like know if from kivy lang I can call external functions, for example:

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '600')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '300')
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)

def testButton():
    print("Woking...")

kw = '''


<Setup>:
    Button:
        on_touch_down: testButton()


    '''

class Setup(RelativeLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Setup, self).__init__(**kwargs)

Builder.load_string(kw)
runTouchApp(Setup())
```

I want that when Press the button, call the function "TestButton()". Its possible?

---

Another Question:
I would like know if I can just create a empty class and add widget dinamically, for example:

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '600')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '300')
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)

def testButton():
    print("Woking...")

kw = '''


<Setup>:
    RelativeLayout:
        Button:

    '''

class Setup():
    def __init__(self):
        # super(Setup, self).__init__(**kwargs)

Builder.load_string(kw)
runTouchApp(Setup())
```

In the first previous code I inherit "RelativeLayout" in Setup class, but in this one I would like create the "RelativeLayout" without inheritade it, its possible??

---

And the last question is, Why I cannot edit the size of the widgets, I put the size, but appear like dont have the code:

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '600')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '300')
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)


kw = '''


<Setup>:
    size: 10, 10
    TextInput:
        size: .1, .1


    '''

class Setup(RelativeLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Setup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # super(Setup, self).__init__(**kwargs)

Builder.load_string(kw)
runTouchApp(Setup())
```

I tried to put the size of the Setup and the TextInput, but Appear very big in the hole windows.

I hope you can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Answer 1

Yes, it is possible to call an inline external function/method or function/method in another Python script. Please refer to the example below for details.

### Example - Answer 1

#### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '600')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '300')
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)


def testButton():
    print("Woking...")


class Setup(RelativeLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Setup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        button = Button(text="Run external method, testButton")
        button.bind(on_press=lambda x: testButton())
        self.add_widget(button)


class TestExtFuncApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Setup()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestExtFuncApp().run()
```

#### testextfunc.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<Setup>:
```

#### Output - Answer 1

[image: Inline External Function/Method Invoked]

## Answer 3

Replace "size: 0.1, 0.1" with "size_hint: 0.1, 0.1". Please refer to the example below for details.

### Example - Answer 3

#### main.py

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '600')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '300')
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)


kw = '''
<Setup>:
    size: 10, 10
    TextInput:
        size_hint: .1, .1
'''


class Setup(RelativeLayout):
    pass


Builder.load_string(kw)
runTouchApp(Setup())
```

#### Output - Answer 3

[image]

Comment: Additionally, size is ignored as long as size_hint is not set to None.